# detect $_POST field name with same part

Tags: php

Hey guys how i can detect $_POST fieldname name with same part in name like this:

```
fieldname = fg_1, fg_2, fg_3, ....;

if($_POST['fg_*']){
    print 'ok';
}else{
    print "fail";
}
```

In my case `$_POST['fg_*']` did not work.

Thank you

Comment: You'd properly need regex.

Comment: can you explain more ty how i can do?

Comment: Here you go http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php